# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED error not caught in addOnFailureListener and Daily free quota is above free limits

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the next Listeners when I am saving some objects on Firestore. All goes well when there is some quota to write but when there is no then the `addOnFailureListener` does not catch the `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` code to use my method `setNextAttemptToWriteInFirestore()`:

```
DocumentReference df = db.collection("notifications").document(someId).collection("users").document(some_key);

Map<String, Object> initialData = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Object> updateObj = new HashMap<>();

for (int key : updates.keySet()) {
    HashMap<String, Object> datainfo = (HashMap<String, Object>) updates.get(key);
    updateObj.put(String.valueOf(key),datainfo);
}

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

if ( currentUser == null ){
    Log.e(TAG, "Not authenticated user. Nothing to do");
    return -1;
}

df.set( updateObj, SetOptions.merge() ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "information stored properly");
        
}).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    if (e instanceof FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        FirebaseFirestoreException firestoreException = (FirebaseFirestoreException) e;
        FirebaseFirestoreException.Code errorCode = firestoreException.getCode();

        if (errorCode == FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED) {
            // Handle RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED exception
            Log.e(TAG,"FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED. Maximum Quota has been reached for today.");
            setNextAttemptToWriteInFirestore();

        } else {
            // Handle other Firestore exceptions
            Log.e(TAG,"Other FirebaseFirestoreException: "+ errorCode.toString());

        }
    } else {
        // Handle other non-Firestore exceptions
        Log.e(TAG,"NON FirebaseFirestoreException");
    }
});
```

On my logcat I can see the warning but I don't know how to catch it:

> Firestore  com.myapp W  (24.2.2) [WriteStream]: (b404780) Stream closed with status: Status{code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, description=Quota exceeded., cause=null}

Additionally, the daily quota is exceeding the 20k writing actions but I don't have any other plan than the free one. Why? Is every writing attempt counted so that this value increases?

[image]

The app clients have a queue to write and they are attempting to write in Firestore every 20 minutes but I cannot stop this routine since I cannot catch the exception code.